# For $\psi_k := \frac{k!}{(2k)!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^2-1)^k$, $\lVert \psi_k \rVert_{L^2[-1,1]} = \frac{k!^2}{(2k)!}\sqrt{\frac{2^{2k+1}}{2k+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Given $\psi_k := \frac{k!}{(2k)!}\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^2-1)^k$, for $k \in \{0,...,n\}$ I need to show that $$\lVert \psi_k \rVert_{L^2[-1,1]} = \frac{k!^2}{(2k)!}\sqrt{\frac{2^{2k+1}}{2k+1}}$$

I can't think of a good way of solving this, how can I cleverly evaluate the integral in this term?

$$\frac{k!}{(2k)!}(\int_{-1}^1 |\frac{d^k}{dx^k}(x^2-1)^k|^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}}$$

Could someone maybe also say whether there is some trick to get the term: $\sqrt{\frac{2^{2k+1}}{2k+1}}$?

Or any hints in general would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Hint: a lot of integration by parts.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I can't find a smart way to use integration by parts here, should you take $f(x)=d^k/dx^k(x^2-1), g'(x)=d/dx(d^{k-1}/dx^{k-1})$, this doesn't lead me anywhere. How do I deal with the absolute value in the l2 norm? Sorry for such basic questions, but I'm terrible at integrating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}((x^2-1)^k)\right)^2dx$$
$$=\int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}((x^2-1)^k)\right) \left(\frac{d^k}{dx^k}((x^2-1)^k)\right) dx$$
$$=\frac{d^k}{dx^k}((x^2-1)^k)\times \frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}((x^2-1)^{k})\big|_{x=-1}^{x=1}  - \int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}}((x^2-1)^k)\right) \left(\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}((x^2-1)^k)\right) dx$$

$$=- \int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{d^{k+1}}{dx^{k+1}}((x^2-1)^k)\right) \left(\frac{d^{k-1}}{dx^{k-1}}((x^2-1)^k)\right) dx$$
$$...=(-1)^k \int_{-1}^1 \left(\frac{d^{2k}}{dx^{2k}}((x^2-1)^k)\right)   (x^2-1)^k   dx$$
$$= (2k)! \int_{-1}^1 (1-x^2)^k   dx,$$
and the latter integral should be easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

The $n$-th [Legendre polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) can be defined through Rodrigues' formula as
$$ P_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n n!}\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(x^2-1)^n \tag{1}$$
hence according to your notation $\psi_k = \frac{2^k}{\binom{2k}{k}} P_k(x)$. Legendre polynomials give an orthogonal base of $L^2(-1,1)$ with respect to the usual inner product:
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} P_n(x)P_m(x)\,dx = \frac{2\delta(m,n)}{2n+1}\tag{2} $$
and the claim readily follows up to rescaling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, we haven't derived Rodriguezs formula, so I don't think I can use it. Do you have a derivation.

Comment: @eager2learn: that is easy to find. It is enough to apply integration by parts multiple times.